# How can I make it so materials are linked to objects instead of data, with Python?

Tags: python, materials

How to add material to selected objects via python?
Material must be linked to Object (not Data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over a button, it will often tell you the python binding that can be used to invoke similar actions to the button. In this case:
[image: Hovering over change link buttons]

So first you assign it a material, and then go and, *from the object*, change the data link.

To set all materials to 'object' for a single material:

```
obj = an_object
for mat_slot in obj.material_slots:
    mat = mat_slot.material
    mat_slot.link = 'OBJECT'
    mat_slot.material = mat
```

I am not sure why re-assigning the material is necessary, but hey, it works!

To set a single material slot (untested):

```
obj = an_object
mat = a_material
mat_slot = [m for m in obj.material_slots if material_slot.material == mat][0]
mat = mat_slot.material
mat_slot.link = 'OBJECT'
mat_slot.material = mat
```

To assign a material, something like this could be written (untested):

```
def applyMaterial(obj, mat, mat_slot=0):
    obj.material_slots[mat_slot].link = 'OBJECT'
    obj.material_slots[mat_slot].material = mat
```

Comment: thank you. It works great.

I need to change several materials (but not all) of the scene which is a copy of another (_New Scene - Link Objects_). I decided to change it using the script :)
Of course, first I used _U - Object_