# Unlinking Materials from Objects that were copied using ob.copy()

Tags: python, objects

I am writing a python program to create a torus comprised of rings of segments. I am to the point where I have the torus nicely generating.
I created objects using this code:

```
aMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Segment" + str(c_index+a))
anObject = bpy.data.objects.new("Segment" + str(a), aMesh)
anObject.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(anObject)
vertsd=[]
for b in range(8):
   vertsd.append((block[b].x,block[b].y, block[b].z))
aMesh.from_pydata(vertsd, [], faces1)
aMesh.update(calc_edges=True)
```

This creates objects named "Segment0" through "Segment8" for example.
Then later, I copy these segments to make all the rings:

```
ob = bpy.data.objects.get(aName)
ob_dup = ob.copy()
```

This results in a bunch of objects named "Segment0.001", "Segment0.002" etc... Then I rotate and translate the segments into a torus.

Now I am to the point where I want to be able to apply different materials to each segment independently. The problem is that if I change the material for "Segment0.003" for example, the material changes for all of "Segment0.001-Segment0.032"

How can I "unlink" the materials for each of the copied segements?
I have been going through all the examples I can find, and they all seem to work by themselves, but not when I port them into my program.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated![image: ![Example of Ring and Torus]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27lMs.png)

Comment: Could also dupe mesh `ob_dup.data = ob_dup.data.copy()` However (IMO) a better approach would be object linking materials https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53188/how-can-i-make-it-so-materials-are-linked-to-objects-instead-of-data-with-pytho

Comment: Thanks batFinger - I got it to work with your line of code. I haven't had luck with the object linking, but I will keep investigating it. Thanks again!